# Не работает @media-screan max-width при 980px

Tags: html, css

Когда задана ширина 1000px в медиа-запросе все ок, но только она становится меньше 980px почему-то не работает, на jsfiddle код работает браузер(chrome). Не могу понять в чем проблема, может кто-то знает как это исправить. Вот код:

```css
#header {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: green;
}

.menu-icon {
  order: 1;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 65%;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
  .container1 {
    display: flex;
    background: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="imgone">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Focus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work Steps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример рабочий, добавьте в пример кода то что у вас находится в `<head>`.

Comment: <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Alexis</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедись что прописан метатег в хеде страницы.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, в этом и была проблема.